# How do I check if a given operation (or system call) is atomic on Linux?

Tags: linux, multiprocessing, atomic

I want to find a reliable way (other than reading the kernel source code) to check if a given operation (or system call) is atomic (in the sense that other process can only see the state before or after that operation, but not something in between) on Linux. The goal of this is to avoid using unnecessary locks for some operations if the kernel already does that for me.

So far I can only find resources like [this](https://rcrowley.org/2010/01/06/things-unix-can-do-atomically.html) about this topic, which is by no means authoritative or exhaustive. Also, the Linux man pages contains little information about this. For example, for most functions mentioned in the above link, I don't find anything about their atomicity in the man pages.

Could anyone tell me if there is a standard or official documentation which provides this information? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I am not a Linux kernel expert, but I would doubt that such a list exists. And you see, what would it help, if you work on your code tomorrow, but Linux 6.4 released in 12.43 months from now ... changes some implementation; and all of a sudden your lock is no longer required; or all of a sudden, you would need one ...

Answer (score 0):

I think POSIX thread-safe functions are a good starting point. Thread-safe functions are functions that will give the same results when called from different threads. This is not at all the same as being atomic, but at least it gives a hint about which functions certainly are not atomic.

POSIX.1-2001 and POSIX.1-2008 require that all functions specified in the standard shall be thread-safe, except for a specific set of functions (most of which are implemented in the standard library and not in the kernel).

As an example of a function that is thread-safe but not atomic, consider `fwrite()`. `fwrite()` will write to a per-process buffer under pthread locks, so it is thread-safe. However, the buffer may be flushed in separate `write()` chunks, so other processes don't see it as an atomic write.

Comment: I tend to think that thread safety and atomicity are actually very different concepts. Thread safety means there is no data race when the function is called from multiple threads simultaneously. Implementation-wise, typically it means the function doesn't use any static or global variables. However, that's not directly related to atomicity in terms of how its effect can be observed by other threads. It is also worth noting that to observe the effects of a function called by one thread, other threads don't need to call the same function at all. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: That's why I said "are a good starting point". I'll update the answer to reflect that distinction.

Comment: Atomic operations are also _async-safe_, which pthread mutexes are not. Specifically, if a thread is holding a mutex when it's served a signal, the async signal handler won't be able to grab it.

Comment: I don't think that that's what the OP was talking about.